# Access stylesheet in a jar on jsp page

Tags: jsp, jar, stylesheet

I add a jar in shared tomcat 5.5 zone.
This jar has only css et icons.
How can I link stylesheet of the jar in a JSP page in my web application.

Thank's.

Answer (score 0):

You can but you need some manual coding, as default servlet does know nothing about your jars. You need to implement your own servlet that can read data from classpath and map it to some URL, which you will then use in JSP. I can suggets you looking at following blog, it could be used as template:

http://www.cribbstechnologies.com/2011/06/22/loading-css-from-a-jar-file-evaluating-el/